# RestAPI Data transfer restriction

Tags: json, rest, limit

Is there a way to allow for a restcall to receive json data for presentation in the callers UI at the time of the call but prevent the user from being able to write the data to a datastore

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I want to be able to stop people storing the response data sent over my restapi